# How can i query one table, and return the result as two tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to query a table that contains a column with two types of data, and i want to get the result of this query as two separate tables so i can handle the data separately.

The column contains : Street Name and Town name, and i want as a result two tables : one for the Street Name, and the second for the town name.

Example of the column that contains two sorts of data that i want to separate :[Click to view img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0nnR.jpg)
i want the street_name as a column, and same for the town_name

Comment: Are you sure you mean two tables, not a result set with two columns (which you can get with a pivot operation)? How will you process two tables...? And how do distinguish the type of data being held? Sample data and expected results would help, as would a bit more explanation of what you're trying to do.

Comment: Hi @Smylif3, you have a table with a column that contains two sorts of data not type's and you want results in two separate columns right?

Comment: Hi @VBoka, Yes this is exactly what i want.

Comment: Hi @Smylif3 please can you provide us a small sample of data (few rows that will show us what are we dealing with and few rows what you expect to get at the end). Just click edit under the question and add this data. You do not need to complicate just a small sample that will give us a better picture of everything. Cheers!

Comment: Please add sample data and results as plain text, not as images. Is there another column that links a pair of street and town names together - e.g. a customer ID?

Comment: I uploaded a picture of the table

Answer (score 0):

// **Table 1**

```
select * 
from table
where postaladdress = 'street_name'
```

// **Table 2**

```
select * 
from table
where postaladdress = 'town_name'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one way(lets say your table is called `test`):

```
  SELECT CASE WHEN UPPER(POSTALADRESS) = UPPER('STREET_NAME') THEN POSTALADRESSVALUE END A, 
           CASE WHEN UPPER(POSTALADRESS) = UPPER('TOWN_NAME') THEN POSTALADRESSVALUE END B
  FROM TEST;
```

This is one more way:

```
SELECT A.STREET_NAME, B.TOWN_NAME from 
(select coalesce(POSTALADRESSVALUE, '' ) STREET_NAME, POSTALADRESS
FROM test T
where UPPER(POSTALADRESS) = UPPER('STREET_NAME')) A
full outer join
(SELECT coalesce(POSTALADRESSVALUE, '' ) TOWN_NAME, POSTALADRESS
FROM test
where UPPER(POSTALADRESS) = UPPER('TOWN_NAME')) B
on a.POSTALADRESS = b.POSTALADRESS;
```

But if there is any connection between the data in this two ways it will not be "shown". All you will get is street names in one column and city names in another.

[Here is a small demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=8265c7fb8c1aa4ef3fc8f9042e339b15)

P.S. If you use the first method then you will have some null values in both columns and if you use second one you will not.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on version 11gR2 or higher, and assuming you have some key column that links together pairs of street and town names, you can use a pivot operation:

```
select *
from your_table
pivot (
  max(postaladressvalue) 
  for (postaladress) in ('street_name' as street, 'town_name' as town)
)
```

Demo with sample data, including a made-up `some_key` to link the rows together, in a CTE:

```
with your_table (some_key, postaladress, postaladressvalue) as (
  select 1, 'street_name', 'adresse postale' from dual
  union all
  select 2, 'street_name', 'AdresseNONSWIFT' from dual
  union all
  select 3, 'street_name', 'ADRESSE POSTALE' from dual
  union all
  select 4, 'street_name', 'WAdressPost' from dual
  union all
  select 4, 'town_name', 'WAdressPost2' from dual
  union all
  select 5, 'street_name', 'CU133POSADD1' from dual
  union all
  select 5, 'town_name', 'CU133POSADD2' from dual
  union all
  select 6, 'street_name', 'as postale' from dual
  union all
  select 7, 'street_name', 'YOUNESPOS1' from dual
  union all
  select 7, 'town_name', 'YOUNESPOS2' from dual
  union all
  select 8, 'street_name', 'adresse postale' from dual
)
select *
from your_table
pivot (
  max(postaladressvalue)
  for (postaladress) in ('street_name' as street, 'town_name' as town)
)
order by some_key;
```

which gets:

```
  SOME_KEY STREET          TOWN           
---------- --------------- ---------------
         1 adresse postale                
         2 AdresseNONSWIFT                
         3 ADRESSE POSTALE                
         4 WAdressPost     WAdressPost2   
         5 CU133POSADD1    CU133POSADD2   
         6 as postale                     
         7 YOUNESPOS1      YOUNESPOS2     
         8 adresse postale
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=c431eccdf311d8720a0fa1b3f42c6831)

If there are other columns you might need a subquery on `your_table` to only select the ones you're interested in before you pivot.

Internally a pivot is essentially the same logic @VBoka showed.